# how can I change the geometry name in abc file by python

Tags: python, maya, alembic

I export the animation into alembic file in maya 2014. 
Then, I want to import it and connect to a render model by the Abcimport.
But,the render model's shape is not same  such as :
the abc model's shape :   aaaShapeDeformed
the render model's shape : aaaShape

and the namespace is also not same

so the Abcimport -connect is not work

how can i do..

can I use the pyAlembic to change the model name in abc file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that. When you import the abc file into Maya, it creates an abc Node in the Maya scene. If the object name doesn't match your scene's object name, you can connect it manually.

The way you do this is as follows.

[image]

The alembic node has a bunch of output plug Arrays, like `outPolyMesh`, `outNSurface` etc. These contain the outputs. If your render object is a mesh, you will be able to find the corresponding output plug inside the `outPolyMesh` array. In your connections editor, just connect the corresponding `outPolyMesh[i]` plug into your `inMesh` plug of your render model's shape node.